# Escaped HTML in dialog to select moderator message template

Tags: bug, moderator-tools, moderator-messages, html-entities

When selecting a moderator message template, the first few lines of the text are shown, but with escaped HTML:

[image]

This is how it looks like in the editor:

[image]

The same problem also happens in a site-specific template we have on Meta.SE, for users who ask programming questions here.